# How can I run a python code with Keras module in VS Code and Ubuntu?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, keras

The OS is Ubuntu16.04. I have installed python extension for VS Code. I can run a Hello World program in VS Code. But when there is `import keras` in the code, I encounter an error:

`[Running] python "/home/lym/Documents/py/test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lym/Documents/py/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    import keras
ImportError: No module named keras`

The code is [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py). I can run this code in terminal. But it seems that VS Code don't recognize the Keras module.

Thanks!

Comment: Is keras installed?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Yes. I can run this code in terminal without any problems.

Comment: Did you check python version is used in VS Code? Maybe you install `keras` by python3 but VS Code is using python2 or vice versa

Comment: @tuannv562 That's the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

most likely you are using different python versions in VS code and terminal:

check your python path in VS code:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

and compare it to the result of this code in your terminal:

```
which python
```