# Sklearn working in terminal but not in Pycharm

Tags: scikit-learn, pycharm

Question is as stated.  Running the sample code for the Naive Bayes module in Sklearn, the program runs no problem when I enter the code directly into the terminal.

However, when I enter the same code into PyCharm, I get the following error:

"No module named naive_bayes"

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you have multiple environments make sure your pycharm uses the env where the package is installed. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run a python code with Keras module in VS Code and Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46273712/how-can-i-run-a-python-code-with-keras-module-in-vs-code-and-ubuntu)