# Says No module named selenium when I have already installed it

Tags: python, selenium

I've been trying for hours to install selenium and now that I have, I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Family/Documents/open python.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('https://www.python.org')
```

Even when I go onto cmd and try to install it, it keeps saying that the package has already been installed in `python34-Lib-sitepackages`:

> env:C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Users\kaleem
>   Hussain\AppData\Local\Smartbar\Application\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Python34;C:\Python34\Scripts

Comment: Could you paste your `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` env vars? And what is the abs path where you installed selenium?

Comment: Are you sure the Python you're running is the same one that has selenium installed?

Comment: Yes,100% they are both  3.6

Comment: This output shows a bunch of Python 3.4 stuff.

Comment: I uninstalled python 3.4 as I was told to update, this is the video i watched 
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vsswJooDe0

Comment: Someone please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run a python code with Keras module in VS Code and Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46273712/how-can-i-run-a-python-code-with-keras-module-in-vs-code-and-ubuntu)

Comment: How did you install selenium module?

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the selenium with pip and check it is resolved:

```
python -m pip install -U selenium
```